# How can we maintain unique object list without using set?

Tags: java

Suppose we have two employee instances having some common attributes like id,name,address (All values are same ).

I want unique objects list without implementing Set.

Please don’t explain the logic with Primitive data type ,I want the uniqueness with Object type.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it possible to enforce uniqueness on a non-Set? Yes, obviously. But why would you want to when `Set` exists?

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to use a `Set`?

Comment: So basically you're asking how to implement your own `Set`?

Comment: Hi All,

Actually this one was asked in one of the recent interview I faced.Can anybody put a sample code ?

Comment: This is a terrible interview question. It's not functional and it's not problem solving. You either already know how to do this properly, or you just spend 5 minutes looking up how to do it properly. In the future, if you don't already know the algorithm by heart, just say you will google the algorithm for doing it efficiently. (You can't know everything, no shame in looking up basic information)

Comment: (Also, a HashTable is technically not a set)

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you create a "collection" class that calls uses the `equals()` method of "incoming" objects to compare them against already stored objects.

If that method gives all `false` - no duplicate, you add to the collection. If `true` - not unique. No adding.

In other words - you re-invent the wheel and create something that resembles a Java set. Of course, with all the implicit drawbacks - such as repeating implementation bugs that were fixed in the Java set implementations 15 to 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a `Set`, use a `List`. All you need to know to implement uniqueness checking logic is what[`equals(Object other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method does:

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one

Now you can test an incoming object against all objects currently on your list, and add it if a match is not found.

Obviously, performance of this method of maintaining a unique collection of objects is grossly inferior to both hash-based and ordering-based sets.

Comment: If you are going for the technicality answer, just use Hashtable. Same functionality, but technically not a set =P

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a `Set` for holding unique instances of your `Employee` class, you can use a `List`. This requires you to do two things:

- Override `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in `Employee` to contain the equality logic. This you would need even if you used a `Set`.
- Each time you add items to the list, use [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) for checking whether an equal object is already in the list. The method will internally use your `Employee.equals()` implementation. Add an item only if it's not already in the list. Note that this method is quite inefficient as it needs to iterate through the whole list in worst case (when an item is not already in the list).